# Can I lock a reference-image to view?

Tags: camera, sculpting

[image: Example]

Can I lock this reference-image so it stays in my view like a sticker on the screen when i move around in the viewport? It would be really helpful when looking at my references without having to move around the camera or images to look at them from the right angle when sculpting.

Comment: I don't know if you can do that inside blender, but I recommend the app PureRef. In it you can create a board with reference images and it has option to always be on top of other windows even if it isn't in focus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can check "lock to object" and choose your camera.

[image]

Then press "toggle to camera view"

[image]

so that you are looking through your camera.

Then parent your reference image to the camera and by this you will always the your referenced image as you want.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I just split the window and open the image in an Image Editor window beside the main 3D view window.